# Prove that $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{u(x+\Delta x) - u(x)}{\Delta x}$ equals to another expressions

Tags: limits, derivatives, proof-verification

Let be $u(x)$ a function $C^k$ where $k>=1$, it's said that:

$\frac{\delta u}{\delta x}(x)=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{u(x+\Delta x) - u(x)}{\Delta x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{u(x)-u(x-\Delta x)}{\Delta x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{u(x+\Delta x)-u(x-\Delta x)}{2\Delta x} $

How could i prove these equalities are true? Let's assume the first equality

$\frac{\delta u}{\delta x}(x)=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{u(x+\Delta x) - u(x)}{\Delta x}$ is true by definition.

How can i make a derivation using some formal properties to reach from the 1st to the 2nd and 3rd equalities?

Not interested on the geometrical proof but a direct proof btw

Comment: Sure that you want to write $\lim_{x\to 0}$ and not $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}$?

Answer (score 1):

From 1st to 2nd: Switch the sign of $\Delta x$ in your limit. Basically write $-\Delta x$ instead of $\Delta x$. This works since the limit does not care, if it as approached from above or below.

From 2nd to 3rd:
$$\frac{u(x+\Delta x)-u(x-\Delta x)}{2\Delta x}=\frac{u(x+\Delta x) -u(x)+u(x)-u(x-\Delta x)}{2\Delta x}=\frac{u(x+\Delta x)-u(x)}{2\Delta x}+\frac{u(x)-u(x-\Delta x)}{2\Delta x}.$$
Now use the already proven equality and you are done.

Comment: Hi, I was reviewing my pending questions on math.stackexchange and I've noticed this particular interesting one... I can't recall very well why at the time I asked I hadn't validated but maybe the reason was because I considered the `From 1st to 2nd` explanation wasn't as good (algebraically speaking) as the `From 2nd to 3rd` explanation. If you feel interested to improve it a bit I can validate... thanks. Don't get me wrong... the explanation makes sense but I'd like to see a more formal proof instead :)